# Create arrays sorted on date timestamps

Tags: twig

I'm trying to create 3 arrays of propducts which are created based on a timestamp.
I'm working on a SaaS platform so I have to create those arrays in the frontend while creating a function in the backend would be better but that's not possible.

The idea is to create 3 arrays for a lottery. So 1 is for current lotteries, 1 for upcoming ones and 1 for recent lotteries.

The problem I have is that it won't sort correctly. So for example the oputput shows 24th of april before 24th of March.

So what I have is this:

```
{% set curr_date = "now"| date('U') %}
{% set current_draws = [] %}
{% set upcoming_draws = [] %}
{% set recent_draws = [] %}
    
{% for product in products %}
    {% if product.data_01 %}
        {% set data_01_date = product.data_01 | date('U') %} //make timestamp for this product
    
        {% if data_01_date > curr_date %} //check if is upcoming or current
            {% if loop.first %} //if 1st in loop then it's current draw
                {% set current_draws = current_draws | merge([product]) %}
            {% else %}
                {% set upcoming_draws = upcoming_draws | merge([product]) | sort((a, b) => a.data_01_date <=> b.data_01_date ) | reverse %} 
                //reverse because lowest timestamp need to be showed first
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% set recent_draws = recent_draws | merge([ product ]) | sort((a, b) => a.data_01_date <=> b.data_01_date ) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}    
{% endfor %}
```

As output for the upcoming draws array I get the following:

```
{% for product in upcoming_draws %}
    {{ product.data_01 | date("U") }}
{% endfor %}

1648162800 // 25th March
1650751200 // 24th April
1648249200 // 26th March
1648335600 // 27th March
```

Why in above example is 24th of April showed before 26th of March?
Any idea how to fix that?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @DarkBee: It's a SaaS platform as told. I don't have access to the backend so I'm looking for a "frontend solution" :)

Comment: Skimmed through the first part to quick I assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. You have a typo, the property is called `data_01`, as seen here `{% set data_01_date = product.data_01|date('U') %}`
2. Don't sort the array during the creation of the array, that's a waste of performance
3. The property `data_01` is a string, you shouldn't compare strings in your `sort`

```
{% set curr_date = "now"| date('U') %}
{% set current_draws = [] %}
{% set upcoming_draws = [] %}
{% set recent_draws = [] %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% if product.data_01 %}
        {% set data_01_date = product.data_01 | date('U') %} //make timestamp for this product

        {% if data_01_date > curr_date %} //check if is upcoming or current
            {% if loop.first %} //if 1st in loop then it's current draw
                {% set current_draws = current_draws | merge([product]) %}
            {% else %}
                {% set upcoming_draws = upcoming_draws | merge([product]) %}
                //reverse because lowest timestamp need to be showed first
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {% set recent_draws = recent_draws | merge([ product ]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for product in upcoming_draws|sort((a, b) => a.data_01|date('U')  <=> b.data_01|date('U') | reverse  ) %}
    {{ product.data_01 | date("d-m-Y") }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#b3ca65fc81)

Comment: Thx for your answer. However that still gives me the same result. Starting to wonder if that sort filter even works correctly... I think the problem is indeed sorting on a string (data_01). I tiried the same with sorting on ID and that works with your code. Do you know perhaps a way to sort on that data_01? Perhaps by setting data_01 as key in an array and the actual timestamp as value? Anyway thx for the help, as always with twig :)

Comment: Check the demo I've posted. The output seems to be correct there (although my demo doesn't have the filter `reverse`). Also do note the snippet uses `a.data_01|date('U')` in the sort